# If I want to find the dimension of the image of a linear transformation...

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

If I have a linear transformation $T(v)=Av$ and want to find the dimension of the range$(T)$, the following procedure is valid?

Looking at the columns of $A$, if all columns are linearly independent, then the dimension of the image is the number of columns in $A$.

Answer (score 3):

Yep, that works. But, you should be able to explain *why* it's valid.

Here's a hint to get you started: $Av$ is a linear combination of the columns of $A$, where the coefficients are the entries in $v$. It follows that the range of $T$ is spanned by the columns of $A$. Does that help?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the Rank -Nullity theorem, the answer is yes: the number of columns in your matrix is the sum of the nullity --dimension of the space mapping to $0$ plus the dimension of the image of the matrix. This is equivalent to the number of independent columns plus the complement ( number of columns - number of independent columns), which is equivalent to the kernel.